# Access files in obb file

Tags: java, android

I created an obb file by using WinRar, setting the archive format to 'ZIP' and the compression method to 'store'. I have this file uploaded for testing on Google Play and it is downloaded on my device. I'm trying to access the files inside and first I tried:

```
try {
        expansionFile = APKExpansionSupport.getAPKExpansionZipFile(context,46, 1);
        InputStream fileStream = expansionFile.getInputStream("/plane120large.jpg");
        Log.d("NICK","File Stream: "+fileStream.available());

    }catch(IOException i){
        Log.d("NICK","IOException........"+i.getMessage());
    }
```

and this throws the `IOException` along with the log message `V/zipro: Not a Zip archive`.

When I try to just access a file inside such as: `imageView.setImageURI(Uri.fromFile(new File("/storage/emulated/0/Android/obb/com.nick.app/main.46.com.nick.app.obb/plane120large.jpg")));` I get a file does not exist error.

What is the correct way to access the files inside the obb file?